# Wait for user action after app install request?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a background service that is responsible for checking for updates from a server.

The services launches an AsyncTask, which is responsible for the actual check and download of update.

Then I launch an intent to request the user to install or cancel the installation

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile(SystemConstants.UPDATE_DOWNLOAD_PATH+fileName)),"application/vnd.android.packagearchive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

In an `Activity` I would `startActivityForResult` but since a `service` has started the request I'm having a hard time figuring out how to wait for user response.

How can I, within the AsyncTask wait until the user has chosen an action?

Thanks

Comment: If the user presses any button, then what you need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having a hard time figuring out how to wait for user response

If you need a feedback then your service should not directly fire this intent. Instead you should have "middle man" in your app, most likely another activity, which will fire that intent instead, once service tells it do that. And since this will be regular activity, you can use `startActivityForResult()`

Yet, I think that you should read about [event bus concept](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) (GreenRobot's, OTTO, Guava's) as this may be helpful for your in-app communication.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, starting a download in background seems like a bad practice to me unless the size of it is very small. The user should be made aware there is an upgrade and asked if it's ok to proceed.

That aside I think you should use `Notification` and `PendingIntent`. When the user click your notification your pending intent will just open an `Activity` that launch your `startActivityForResult()`.

If this check is a periodic task make sure you use a `JobScheduler` to optimize battery usage and avoid your service getting terminated by the OS.